# Get the even and odd letters from a text

Tags: android, string

```
    class oddevens{ 
public static void main(String[] args){      
String A, Even, Odd;      
int a,x,y;      
x=0;      
y=1;        
A="sample text here";         
a=A.length();     
Even="";        
Odd="";        
for(int c=0;c==a;c++) {                               
if(c%2==0){                                 
Even=Even+A.substring(x,y);                                  
x=x+1;                                  
y=y+1;                              
}else{                                  
Odd=Odd+A.substring(x,y);                                  
x=x+1;                                  
y=y+1;                               
}                           
}         
System.out.println("Even: "+Even+", Odd: "+Odd);   
}
}
```

With this code, I try to divide String A by taking the 'even and odd' letters, so the output should look like this:
Even:sml ethr, Odd: apetx ee
But is not showing anything.

Comment: First lession, do not write field's name starting with caps. like `String A, Even, Odd;` should be `String a, even, odd;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your for loop, you have put `c==a` as the condition. Since a for loop runs for as long as that condition is met, your loop does not do anything (since c starts of as 0 and a starts of as the length of A.

It should be `for(int c =0; c<a; c++)`

---

A shorter solution to your problem would be something like this:

```
for(int c = 0; c < A.length(); c++){
    if(c % 2 == 0{
        Even += A.charAt(c);
    }else{
       Odd += A.charAt(c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will never run

```
for(int c=0;c==a;c++) {
.....
}
```

should be

```
for(int c=0;c < a;c++) {
.....
}
```

Anyway, you did not even tell us your problem.